# Connection error in qt5 network

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking

i want to make a program like msn messenger , i have use qt5 with network , when i open a new connection with my local server , it doesn't work , it gave  back to me that my server not connected i don't know the reason

**mainwindow.h**

> ```
> #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
> #define MAINWINDOW_H
>
> #include <QMainWindow>
> #include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
> #include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
>
> namespace Ui {
> class MainWindow;
> }
>
> class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>
> public:
>     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
>     ~MainWindow();
>
> private slots:
>     void on_pushButton_clicked();
>
>     void newConnection ();
>
> private:
>     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
>     QTcpServer *server;
> };
>
> #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
> ```

**mainwindow.cpp**

> ```
> #include "mainwindow.h"
> #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
>
> MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
>     QMainWindow(parent),
>     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
> {
>     ui->setupUi(this);
>     server = new QTcpServer(this);
>
>     connect(server , SIGNAL(newConnection()) , this , SLOT(newConnection()));
>     if(server->listen(QHostAddress::Any , 5050))
>     {
>         ui->label->setText("Not Start");
>     }
>
>     else
>     {
>         ui->label->setText("Server Started Now");
>     }
>
> }
>
> MainWindow::~MainWindow()
> {
>     delete ui;
> }
>
> void MainWindow::newConnection()
> {
>     QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
>
>     socket->write("Hello Islam");
>
>     socket->flush();
>
>     socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
>
>     socket->close();
> }
>
> void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
> {
>     newConnection();
> }
> ```

**this for call library**

> ```
> #-------------------------------------------------
> #
> # Project created by QtCreator 2013-11-03T10:00:37
> #
> #-------------------------------------------------
>
> QT       += core gui network
>
> greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
>
> TARGET = TCPTEST
> TEMPLATE = app
>
>
> SOURCES += main.cpp\
>         mainwindow.cpp
>
> HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
>
> FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
> ```

i tried to call new connection in mainwindow constructor but it didn't work

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Do you mean that this program prints "Not start" for you?

Comment: You have an error in your error checking. If it prints `Not Start`, it actually started: `if(server->listen(...)) ui->label->setText("Not Start");` I.e. listen() returns true, but you act as if it failed.

Comment: +1 to @FrankOsterfeld. And what does any of this have to do with a linker error?

Comment: thanks :) now it working i found that was the error , thanks

Comment: @Michael Burr: I think "Connection error" is what's actually meant, so just unfortunate wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the error was in

> if(server->listen(QHostAddress::Any , 1234))

which it worked but it must be

> if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any , 1234))

to get server started